# Вопрос по множествам в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача:

Формат входных данных
На вход программе в первой строке дается число mm – количество уроков, проведенных с начала учебного года. Далее идёт mm блоков строк, описывающих листки с фамилиями. На первой строке каждого блока указано количество фамилий n_in
i
​
, затем идёт n_in
i
​
строчек с фамилиями тех, кто был на ii-ом уроке.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести фамилии учеников, которые были на всех уроках, отсортированных в лексикографическом порядке. Каждая фамилия должна быть записана на отдельной строке.

Что я написал:

```
    m = int(input())
    myset = {input() for _ in range(int(input()))}
    myset1 = set()
    myset = sorted(myset)
    if m==1:
        print(*myset, sep='\n')
    else:
        for i in range(m-1):
            for j in range(int(input())):
                myset1.add(input())
            myset.intersection_update(myset1)
            myset1.clear()
            myset = sorted(myset)
            for row in myset1:
                print(myset1)
```

Ошибка:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/sandbox/main.py", line 11, in 
myset.intersection_update(myset1)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intersection_update'

Не понимаю почему список, если я указываю как множество?

Пример вводных данных:

3
3
Князев
Сафонов
Майоров
2
Князев
Майоров
1
Майоров

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [`sorted()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp), указанная Вами в строке 4, будет возвращать **список**, а не множество. Разумеется, для списка функция `intersection_update()` не определена, а только для множества.

Для решения проблемы достаточно записать `set(lst)`, где `lst` — Ваш отсортированный (или нет) список. Вдобавок отмечу, что на строке 13 присутствует точно такая же ошибка: множество обратится в список.

К тому же, говоря об остальном коде: при выводе строк из множества-пересечения Вы берёте уже опустошённый ранее буфер `myset1` вместо `myset`. Плюс ещё непонятно, зачем выводить сами множества, если Вы хотите отдельные значения оттуда брать (но это уже на Ваше усмотрение).

```py
m = int(input())
myset = {input() for _ in range(int(input()))}
myset1 = set()
myset = set(sorted(myset))                     # <--
if m==1:
    print(*myset, sep='\n')
else:
    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(int(input())):
            myset1.add(input())
        myset.intersection_update(myset1)
        myset1.clear()
        myset = set(sorted(myset))             # <--
        for row in myset:                      # myset1 -> myset
            print(row)                         # myset -> row
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция `sorted()` возвращает список каждый раз, несмотря на то, какой тип был передан.